# Populate Email Body and Subject from DGV CellClick Event

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I have a datagridview that is being populated through MySQL. One column contains emails and the rows will have data associated to that specific email address. I have the following code entered in the form so when the user clicks the cell with an email address a new message window will open and the email address will be in the mailto section:

```
 Private Sub MyDataGridView_CellClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellClick
    If DataGridView1.Columns(e.ColumnIndex).HeaderText = "Mech Email" Then
        Dim selectedEMailCell As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)
        If selectedEMailCell.Value IsNot Nothing Then
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("mailto:" & selectedEMailCell.Value.ToString & "")
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I want to add in the ability to include information from the other cells in the same row to be included in the subject line and body of the new email window that appears. Here are the columns that I am working with:

**Mech Email**, **Site No** (Subject Line), **Findings** (Body, but I want to add other comments as well), **Days Old** (Body)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick outline of what you need.  I didn't have a chance to throw it into an editor so there might be some typos.  Also, I didn't put in any checks to see if the other cells are empty.  The basic `mailto:` syntax is `mailto:name@mail.com?subject=Hello&?body=Main message`.   One more thing, if your subject or body contains "&" or "?", you may need to filter those out.

```
        Dim selectedEMailCell As DataGridViewCell = DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(e.ColumnIndex)
        Dim selectedEMailRow As DataGridViewRow = DirectCast(DataGridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex)
        With selectedEMailRow
          If selectedEMailCell.Value IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim mailToString As New Stringbuilder
            mailToString.Append("mailto:" & .selectedEMailCell.Value.ToString)
            mailToString.Append("?subject=" & .Cells("Mech Email").value)
            mailToString.Append(.Cells("Site No").value) 
            mailToString.Append("&body=" & .Cells("Findings").value) 
            mailToString.Append(.Cells("Days Old").value) 
            System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(mailToString.ToString & "")
          End If
        End With
```

Comment: works great! the only issue is that i have quite a few cells that have the "&" and "?" symbol. Is there anyone around that?

Comment: @ryb Yes there is.  "All parameters mentioned need to be "escaped", i.e. spaces should be replaced by %20, carriage return/line feeds by %0D%0A, double quotes by %22, single quotes by %27, backslashes by %5C, less than by &lt;, greater than by &gt;, and ampersands by &amp;.